# Can my dimmer run 100 LEDs in series through a bridge rectifier?

Tags: led, dimmer

I have some Varilight dimmer switches which can be set to trailing edge or leading edge mode, The dimmers are marked with a maximum power of 400W for incandescent or 120W for LEDs.

Now, I want to run LEDs, but not LED bulbs, so there are no electronics involved. I'll string 100 LED in series and connect direct to the (bridge rectified) 330VDC. My understanding of LED rating, and the difference between LED rating and incandescent rating, is that domestic LEDs are actually a bit of circuitry in the bulb, and the LED is not seen by the power supply, so is irrelevant. My LEDs run as up to 2A, which is probably too much but I can bring it down to 1A, giving 330W which is less than the incandescent rating of the dimmer but more than the LED rating.

Fitting the dimmer at the start of the circuit, could I ignore the 120W rating? Or set the dimmer to leading edge and pretend the LEDs are acting as resistive loads?

Comment: The dimmer won't work with bare LEDs so the power ratings don't matter, you can't use it regardless. Any reason you don't use a normal power supply with current control for dimming? That is standard for hundreds of watt class lighting.

Answer (score 1):

230VAC has a peak value of 325V DC. But this is only the peak value.

If your LEDs need 300V to light up, they will only glow on the top portion of the sinewave... Without a resistor in series to limit the current, they will also explode, most likely, but that's another question.

Phase cut triac dimming works by chopping the time the mains is on, but that still won't make your LEDs light up until the dimmer position is such that the dimmer lets the peak of the AC waveform through. Then as voltage goes down from the peak, the LEDs will turn off anyway. So the pot on the dimmer will behave more like an on/off rotary switch.

TL/DR: get a dimmable 24 or 48V DC power supply (Meanwell makes tons of those), arrange your LEDs in series strings with a current sharing resistor in each string, parallel your strings, and that will work.

Or get a high voltage constant current LED driver, but that will be difficult to find at 300V/1A due to the lack of LED fixtures of that power on the market...